# What is the meaning of "the shot told"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I can give examples of the use of this expression. Even if I can guess what it means, I don't have any adequate ideas.

[The phrase has been used in this book[1]](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=81IbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT1209&dq=%22the+shot+told%22&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU3ZSCz7LiAhU0xcQBHTcrCOI4ChDoAQgoMAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20shot%20told%22&f=false)

> 1) The shot told; the Irrepressible was silenced; and I profited by
>   the chance to pour in a broadside of another sort.

[And in this book[2]](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=A8urmp33rzEC&pg=PT109&dq=%22the+shot+told%22&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU3ZSCz7LiAhU0xcQBHTcrCOI4ChDoAQhIMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20shot%20told%22&f=false)

> 2) The shot told: they were notoriously the closest-fisted couple in
>   the village.

[And in this book[3]](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=e8ZmDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=Decadent+and+Occult+Works+by+Arthur+Machen+the+shot+told&source=bl&ots=TwDjzTTALq&sig=ACfU3U1efT3dGRG_D1AKV23nhHGQvHrEXQ&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSzJnX17LiAhV2xMQBHf7JCJUQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Decadent%20and%20Occult%20Works%20by%20Arthur%20Machen%20the%20shot%20told&f=false)

> 3) It was about the time that his disappointment became known to
>   everybody, and the shot told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant definition of *shot* in the Oxford English Dictionary is:

> *figurative*. A remark aimed at some one, esp. in order to wound. Also ***cheap shot*** (*North American colloquial*).

The relevant definition for *tell* from the OED is:

> to be effective or efficacious; to have the desired effect

In other words, it means that the remark hit where it was aimed.

Answer (score 2):

Originally the phrase "the shot told" meant that a gunshot had struck the target, and had an effect. You can find it used in this sense in historical novels set during the Napoleonic Wars, for example.

Later, as a metaphor, it indicates that sarcasm, irony, or other possibly hostile speech had had an effect on the person to whom it was addressed.